# Converting an Objective C array declaration to Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift2

How would I translate this Obj-C into Swift? I'm not sure about the new Swift 2 syntax and all.

`unsigned char pixel[4] = {0};`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the comments there seems to be an additional question about what the Objective-C code means: `unsigned char pixel[4]` declares `pixel` as an array of `4` `unsigned char`'s. The `= {0}` *initializes* all elements of the array to `0`.

Hence the simplest conceptual equivalent in Swift is:

```
var pixel: [UInt8] = [0,0,0,0]
```

Unlike C and Objective-C, Swift does not allow specifying the size of the array in advance and thus all four zeroes must be given to obtain the correct length - in C and Objective-C the extra zeroes can be omitted for brevity since it is already known that the array's size is `4`.

Arguably you could use `CUnsignedChar` instead of `UInt8` (as the `unsigned char` in C is not strictly guaranteed to be `UInt8`), but it is unnecessary unless you're going to be passing the values to a C function expecting `unsigned char`. In any case they are extremely likely to be the same type, and on the odd platforms where they aren't the same type it is more likely that the C code is actually wrong and used `unsigned char` where they meant `uint8_t`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way :

```
var pixel = [UInt8](count:4, repeatedValue:0)
```

Or :

```
var pixel:[UInt8] = [0,0,0,0]
```

Comment: So the `{0}` in Obj-C does not refer to a parameter given from the function? Because I'm passing a `CGPoint` to this function, named `point`, I feel like I have to fill the `pixel` array with that data

Answer (score 0):

Swift equivalent of unsigned char is [CUnsignedChar](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html)

```
var pixel : [CUnsignedChar]()
```

You cannot give fixed length arrays in CMutablePointers in swift. So you have to declare like this. [Reference](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/5316)

See this [link](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/4856) to overcome this issue